# how to concatenate a - in a string c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am trying to make a calculator in c# and i am looking to concatenate a - into a string or something similar. the expected output should also minus the two variables. EX,

```
string ready;

       private void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        long minusnumber = 32;

        ready = minusnumber +  "-";


    }
. 
.
.
private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long equalsNumber1 = 32;

        ready += equalsNumber1;
        MessageBox.Show(ready);
    }
```

and console output would be 0
but it is taking  "-" as minus not subtracting the two numbers.
ive tried escaping it (not sure if i did escape it right) and it didn't help:/

Comment: So you're trying to subtract two numbers... ? Can you fix your example.. make it a proper working example of your problem.

Comment: "it is taking "-" as minus not subtracting the two numbers" not sure what you mean by that.  "expected output should also minus the two variables" pretty vague as well.  Try rewording these to be more clear.  Do you want the result to be a string like "32 -" or do you want it to be an integer?

Comment: Seems to me that you are looking for an [Expression Evaluator](http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Side note: "console output" usually means "print into console window" (also known as command line, shell, CMD,...). In you case you use `MessageBox.Show` which will not output anything into console. I suspect you simply misuse the term as your application is probably WinForms one (based on names of methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are hoping to accomplish, but it is a bit unclear.  This will take minusnumber and negate it.  So then when you add previous number to minusnumber, it will in effect subtract.  Only problem with this is your `ready` variable appears to be a string.

```
private void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    long minusnumber = 32;

    ready = -minusnumber;
}
```

Perhaps `ready` should be a long.  When you are getting user input, you can use TryParse:

```
string userText = "54";
long userInput;
Int64.TryParse(userText, out userInput);
ready -= userInput;
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
string.concat(minusnumber , "-");
```

It might help you. You can use n numbers of object on concat method.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've written, the variable `ready` in `minus_Click` is local to `minus_Click` and not the global you probably intended it to be.

Instead of:

```
string ready = minusnumber +  "-";
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
ready = minusnumber +  "-";
```

**EDIT**

Now that the question is patched, it seems that the real question is "Why does `MessageBox.Show(ready);` show "32-32" instead of 0?"  If that *is* the question, the reason is you are showing the value of the variable `ready`.  This is a string.  You started it at `"32-"` then added `"32"`.  The result of this string concatenation is `"32-32"`.  In order to perform arithmetic evaluation you need to write the code to parse the string and do the evaluation.  Or find someone that has written an `Eval()` method for strings containing arithmetic expressions.

Comment: oops forgot to put that out side when posting. it is a local variable in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

For make calculator you must use Polish Notation or RPN